# “A person” versus “some person”

Tags: differences, articles, indefinite-articles, determiners

What is the difference between:

1. There is **a** person in the room.
2. There is **some** person in the room.

Comment: ... Perhaps one should mention the use of 'Some ...' to mean 'What a ...!' as in "Some Chicken! Some Neck!" (Winston Churchill)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*“A person”* implies a singular person.  A single person is in the room.

*“Some person”* is the same thing but goes a step further.  It implies that the one person is somewhat unknown.  It could be a girlfriend, or a violent robber, or something in-between.

*“Some”* implies an unknown.  (e.g. *"Some amount of money."*, or *"Some outcome."* etc.

That's how I see it.  Hope it helps.

Comment: I think it's fair to also add that if you're considering a direct comparison between using an indefinite article (a) and the adjective (some), you would usually suspect that "some person" is meant to be condescending or evoke curiosity. As phrased in the question, the second option of "some person" exhibits an apprehension towards the statement itself. Especially because the action ("is [...] in the room") is so banal, "some" isn't describing "a few" persons, it's noting that this current person is almost "some kind of person" who is in this room. A very wary statement.